# Wordpress Woocommerce Variation Not Resolving

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

my wordpress website has woocommerce installed with multiple tshirts and variations. When I click on the variations button within a specific product, I get the pinwheel and the backend just keeps loading. It never resolves.

Also worth nothing is that I have tried deleting all plugins except Woocommerce and this still happens. At the moment, I am also unable to delete any plugins on the site. The site just loads and loads and never resolves.

I'm assuming something funky is messing with the coding on the site. Anyone ever experienced this before or know what I can try?

Comment: has your server the requirements for running Woocommerce? Because that may be a memory problem.Have you tried deleting the plugins directly on your server?

Comment: Yeah, I've followed Woocommerce's suggested settings. I've also tried deleting all the plugins from the backend to see if that took care of the glitch that wouldn't let me change variations but that didn't work. When I try to delete plugins, sometimes I get this error: Deletion failed: <!DOCTYPE html>Page not found - Finger Lakes Shirts {"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Organization","url":"https:\/\/www.fingerlakesshirts.com\/","sameAs":["https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/fingerlakesshirts\/","https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/fingerlakesshirts\/",